# How 2d array is assign to 1D array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am using apache commons-math library to calculate regression parameter. As shown in figure 2nd and 3rd line, a 2d array is assigned to single array. When i use same code,

I am getting error:

> "Type mismatch error:cannot convert from double [][] to double []" in
>   3rd line but not for 2nd line.

```
OLSMultipleLinearRegression regression = new OLSMultipleLinearRegression();
double[] y = new double[]{11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0};
double[] x = new double[6][];
x[0] = new double[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
x[1] = new double[]{2.0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
x[2] = new double[]{0, 3.0, 0, 0, 0};
x[3] = new double[]{0, 0, 4.0, 0, 0};
x[4] = new double[]{0, 0, 0, 5.0, 0};
x[5] = new double[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 6.0};          
regression.newSample(y, x);
```

why this is happening? and how this works?

[More details on OLS regression are given here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html)

Comment: Please don't post code-image next time.

Comment: thank you. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1 :**

```
   double[] y = new double[]{11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0};
```

You are creating a 1D array with values inserting it right away. Works fine

**Case 2 :**

```
double[] x = new double[6][];
```

You are declaring a 1D array and trying to assign a 2D array. Which is illegal.

Either change your declaration to 2D or initialize with 1D

valid declarations will be

```
double[] x = new double[6];  // 1D
```

or

```
double[][] x = new double[6][lenghtYouWant]; //2D
```

After seeing the insertions later on you are wanting a 2D array. To compile the below code successfully you need to change the delcaration to

```
double[][] x = new double[6][];
```

Comment: I haven't written this code, i just copied from  apache commons-math library website. I guess, they can't give wrong information. there must be some explanation.

Comment: That's not an IDE to compile and give the errors. After a ll a simple web page. There must be some typo.